# Adding custom fonts in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, zurb-foundation-5

I am trying to add a custom font that I downloaded in my Rails App. This is what I did: I downloaded the font (Georgia.tff) and put it in `app/assets/fonts/Georgia.tff`. My main CSS file looks like this:

foundation-and-override.scss

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "Georgia";
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Georgia.ttf) format("truetype");
  }

.header {
    font-family: "Georgia";
}
```

and this is where I want to apply the font:

_header.html.erb

```
<header class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="header">
      <h1><a href="/">SMART INVESTORS'S CLUB</a></h1>
  </ul>
</header>
```

It's not working. I'm using Rails 4.2.1.
I referenced [adding custom font in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708127/adding-custom-font-in-my-app) and [Official way of adding custom fonts to Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250303/official-way-of-adding-custom-fonts-to-rails-4). No luck.

Comment: The url method does not compute a path to an asset but merely returns the full path used for a request.

Answer (score 3):

foundation-and-override.scss

`@font-face{
  font-family:"Georgia";
  src:asset-url("Georgia.ttf") format("truetype");
}`

In application.rb you have to add:

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')`

And font file "Georgia.ttf" must be in `app/assets/fonts/Georgia.ttf`

Answer (score 3):

Rails provides the font-url helper method for exactly this:

```
@font-face{
  font-family:'Georgia';
  src:font-url('Georgia.ttf');
}
```

You can also just use asset-url:

```
@font-face{
  font-family:'Georgia';
  src:asset-url('Georgia.ttf');
}
```

By default Sprockets should be able to find any file in your assets folder, so no additional config should be needed.

Comment: and this even throws in too many errrors. I think the version of Rails matter here.

Comment: No, these are both valid options in 4.2.1 :/ There may be a problem with how your app compiles the assets. What errors are you getting?